# add text to the top of category page

Tags: categories

I want to add the text to top of each category page. I am using a plugin **http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/categorycustomfields/** . With the help of this plugin, i am able to add extra field to my categories, but how can i display that. eg :-  if i want to display category description, i used `<?php   echo category_description();  ?>`
similarly, how can i display custom field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest using one plugin that I use for my sites ( I am a web-developer)? I Use Extra category content plugin (http://www.greatwpplugins.com/extra-category-content/) if I want to put any kind of content (text, image, link, etc) before the post listing in a category. Just install the plugin, edit a category to add some extra content and add in the template the code `<?php echo the_extra_category_content( ); ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin there's a description textarea for adding some extra text to each category. In your template file you can show this text via the [`category_description($cat_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) function.

Alternatively, you could also use the [`is_category($cat_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) function to check whether a certain category is being displayed and then do whatever you want in there.

```
if (is_category(5))
{
  // Description for the current category
  echo category_description();
  // Add some extra content
  echo 'This is category number five, yay!';
}
```

Note that you can use the category [template files](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) as well:

`category-$slug.php` > `category-$id.php` > `category.php`

Comment: Thanx, actually i was in need of extra field. I used the category custom field plugin. but the problem is how can i display that.

Comment: For eg if i want to display description , i use <?php
         echo category_description();
?>, similarly, not getting, how to display custom field

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Please, update the original question with extra information.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my qustn